# How to get an Item from an auto-populated DataGrid?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagrid, cell, anonymous-types

I have a DataGrid that is automatically fed certain values from an LINQ-To-SQL-Source. The headers of the DataGrid are also auto-generated. I simply want one of the Cells of the currently selected item within the data-grid.

`var a = TestGrid.SelectedCells[0].Item;`

If I debug this I get a List containing all the values I need:

`TestGrid.SelectedCells[0].Item{ Datum = {11.05.2011 00:00:00}, ID = 3, name = "db",Status = "Ready" }<Anonymous Type>`

I have absolutely no idea how to select the second item(ID) from that anonymous type, and google isn't helping

Comment: p.s., It looks strange to be getting back an anonymous object when you access the cell.  If anything, you should be getting that if accessing a row.  Seeing what your query looks like would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to create a type to hold your values and store that in your DataGrid.  If you're only using it for display, the anonymous types are fine to use.  The moment you need to use them for anything else, they are not so great.

If you really want to stick to anonymous types, the only option you have is to use reflection.  If this is specifically a C# 4.0+ app, then using `dynamic` can make this somewhat easier.

Comment: The problem with that is that right now I get the data in the following way: `var query = search(foo); TestGrid.ItemsSource = query;`, with the results from search being the way shown above. I'm not using anonymous types for convenience but rather because I don't really know how else I can get the data into the grid without hard-coding/iterating values/headers.

Comment: @fk2: Is this a WinForms app?  WPF?  Web?  Column generation is completely automatic in WPF and WinForms AFAIK.

Comment: Well, I now ended up simply making a type with the amount of fields needed and properties in question. A hell to type, but it works. Thanks for your help!